# Transposing JSON Data in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to transpose a query result into a matrix. Essentially if I had this result:

| Attribute1 | Val | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Val 1 | 100 |
| Bananas | Val 1 | 200 |
| Apples | Val 2 | 300 |
| Bananas | Val 2 | 400 |

I want to transpose it to this:

| Attribute1 | Val 1 | Val 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 100 | 300 |
| Bananas | 200 | 400 |

However the number of values in the Attribute field & Val field are dynamic. How would I therefore go about transposing this in JS so my output JSON array is a dynamic structure dependent on the query result?

I've got a code snippet below where I've listed out the distinct [Attribute1] & [Val], but how do I build a json array where the definition is dynamic? I've made a stab at it at the end, but I know it's not right yet...

```
var res = [{
    "Attribute1": 'Apples',
    "Val": 'Val 1',
    "Count": 100
  },
  {
    "Attribute1": 'Bananas',
    "Val": 'Val 1',
    "Count": 200
  },
  {
    "Attribute1": 'Apples',
    "Val": 'Val 2',
    "Count": 300
  },
  {
    "Attribute1": 'Bananas',
    "Val": 'Val 2',
    "Count": 400
  }
]


const y_result = [];
const map = new Map();
for (const item of res) {
  if (!map.has(item.Attribute1)) {
    map.set(item.Attribute1, true); // set any value to Map
    y_result.push({
      Attribute1: item.Attribute1,
    });
  }
}
console.log(y_result)

const x_result = [];
const x_map = new Map();
for (const item of res) {
  if (!x_map.has(item.Val)) {
    x_map.set(item.Val, true); // set any value to Map
    x_result.push({
      Attribute1: item.Val,
    });
  }
}
console.log(x_result)

let tmp
let new_res

console.log(y_result[0].Attribute1)
for (const item of y_result) {
    tmp = { y_result[0].Attribute1 : item.Count };
  new_res.push(tmp)
}
console.log(new_res)
```

Comment: wow, 2 other great answers while I was writing up mine :) upvoting both! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way..

```js
const res = 
  [ { Attribute1: 'Apples',  Val: 'Val 1', Count: 100 } 
  , { Attribute1: 'Bananas', Val: 'Val 1', Count: 200 } 
  , { Attribute1: 'Apples',  Val: 'Val 2', Count: 300 } 
  , { Attribute1: 'Bananas', Val: 'Val 2', Count: 400 } 
  ] 

const y_result = Object.entries(res.reduce((a,{Attribute1,Val,Count})=>
    {
    a[Attribute1]      = a[Attribute1] ?? {}
    a[Attribute1][Val] = Count
    return a
    },{})).map(([Attribute1,vals])=>({Attribute1, ...vals}))
    
console.log( y_result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Nice! My approach was to use a global variable, you avoide that by building an object and then `map`ping its entries into an array, love it.

Answer (score 1):

My approach, using some [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

- Go through every item in the array
- Check its `Attribute1` value and check if its been seen before.
- If it has read the `Val` property add it to the existing object
- If not create the object, read the `Val` property and set it.

**Code:**

```js
var res = [
    { Attribute1: "Apples", Val: "Val 1", Count: 100  },
    { Attribute1: "Bananas", Val: "Val 1", Count: 200 },
    { Attribute1: "Apples", Val: "Val 2", Count: 300  },
    { Attribute1: "Bananas", Val: "Val 2", Count: 400 },
];

let result = [], seenBefore = [];

res.forEach(({ Attribute1, Count, Val }) => {
    let foundHere = seenBefore.indexOf(Attribute1)
    
    if (foundHere !== -1){
      result[foundHere][Val] = Count;
    }
    else {
      result.push({ Attribute1, [Val]: Count });
      seenBefore.push(Attribute1)
    }
}) 

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Not bad at all :)

Comment: Thank you for your help - also a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

The snippet below does the job in 2 stages: first the value of `Val` becomes the key and takes the value of `Count` as its own value, and then it merges all values together. The second step is done with the help of the `registry` object that allows to add all keys that are not `Attribute1` to an already existing entry if it had been pre-recorded there.

```js
const res = [
  {
    Attribute1: 'Apples',
    Val: 'Val 1',
    Count: 100,
  },
  {
    Attribute1: 'Bananas',
    Val: 'Val 1',
    Count: 200,
  },
  {
    Attribute1: 'Apples',
    Val: 'Val 2',
    Count: 300,
  },
  {
    Attribute1: 'Bananas',
    Val: 'Val 2',
    Count: 400,
  },
];

const registry = {};

const result = res
  .map(
    ({ Attribute1, Val, Count }) => ({
      Attribute1,
      [Val]: Count,
    }),
    []
  )
  .reduce((acc, row, i) => {
    const at = row.Attribute1;

    if (!(at in registry)) {
      registry[at] = i;
      acc.push(row);
      return acc;
    }

    Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key !== 'Attribute1') {
        acc[registry[at]][key] = value;
      }
    });

    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```